# Calculate from exist table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to count data from exist table which the date is today. And everyday it counts automaticaly.

I have `pembayaran` table that include 'tanggal' column as date and 'total' column as number that i will count.
I've tried this code. But it always give me '0'. Did i forget something?

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
               $today = date('Y-m-d');
               $where = array('tanggal' => $today);
               $getpem = $this->aruskas_m->selectX('pembayaran',$where)->result();
               $jumlah =0;
               foreach ($getpem as $row) {
                   $jumlah += $row->total;
               }
               $data['kasmasuk'] = $jumlah;        

               $this->load->view('laporan/aruskas_v', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Please give `->aruskas_m->selectX` function detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$where = array('tanggal' => $today);
```

to

```
$where = array('date(tanggal)='. $today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your date field's format is exactly like this `Y-m-d` format. Otherwise you have to change the date format of `$today` perfectly matching with `tanggal` field in your condition  `$where = array('tanggal' => $today);`